# Where can I find the original, drunken version of Screaming Jay Hawkins' I Put a Spell On You online?

Tags: identify-this-song, recording

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screamin%27_Jay_Hawkins) that Screaming Jay Hawkins' very first recording of the song that would both define his image from thereon and cement him as one of the pioneers of modern [shock rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_rock) was recorded in 1955, during a recording session in which the entire band was drunk, making the finished product an entirely different production to what they'd originally intended. As I understand the story, this recording was deemed too "sexually overt" for the radio, and the famous version of the song that Hawkins has popularly come to be associated with was released by the label in 1956.

**I'm wondering where I can find the original, uncensored, drunken recording of the song in all its glory?** Wikipedia also says that version was later re-released on the CD "The Whamee 1953–55", but I've not been able to find it on YouTube or anywhere else online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on you profile it seems like you're located in UK, in which case it should be fairly easy to find that version of the song, since that compilation was released in the UK. [Here it is on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=The%20Whamee%201953%E2%80%9355&sprefix=cards%20aga%2Caps%2C156); the song is available for download for £0.99, or you can download the full album or buy the full CD. I've also been able to find a sample of it [on AllMusic](http://www.allmusic.com/album/the-whamee-1953-55-mw0000771262), though unfortunately it seems as though you can only hear about 30 seconds of it. In addition, I've found the album for sale on the [US eBay site](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Screamin-Jay-Hawkins-The-Whamee-1953-1955-Screamin-Jay-Hawkins-CD-9SVG-/302056913122?hash=item4653feb8e2:g:dTsAAOSwe8tXMc-R).

Hopefully this helps!